# How to path args to shouldVisit() method in crawler4j?

Tags: web-crawler, crawler4j

I want to pass arguments to should Visit() method in crawler4j .
I saw example for documentation library page on github which uses Factory way but I cant understand it..
Please someone provide a sample example to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

## Variant 1: Injecting additional parameters as constructor arguments

Additionl arguments besides the method parameters of `shouldVisit(...)`, need to be passed as constructor arguments into every single `WebCrawler` class.

That means, you can do the following to achieve it by using a `factory` class:

`MyWebCrawler.class` with two custom arguments (`customArgument1` and `customArgument2`):

```
public class MyWebCrawler extends WebCrawler {

    private final String customArgument1;
    private final String customArgument2;

    public MyWebCrawler(String customArgument1, String customArgument2) {
        this.customArgument1 = customArgument1;
        this.customArgument2 = customArgument2; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url) {
        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
        return customArgument1.equals(href) || customArgument2.equals(href);;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

For this to work, the `factory` should be something like this:

```
public class MyCrawlerFactory implements CrawlController.WebCrawlerFactory<MyWebCrawler> {

        public MyCrawlerFactory newInstance() throws Exception {
        return new MyCrawlerFactory("some argument", "some other argument");
    }
}
```

Every time a new instance of `MyWebCrawler` is created, you can pass your custom arguments.

To use the factory, you would start the crawling process from your `CrawlController` like this:

```
controller.start(new MyCrawlerFactory(), numberOfCrawlers);
```

A similar working example can be found [at the official GitHub repository](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/tree/master/crawler4j-examples/crawler4j-examples-postgres).

## Variant 2: Using `CrawlController#getCustomData()` (deprecated)

You can use `customData` on the `CrawlController` object to inject additional data into your web-crawler objects. However, this is the deprecated way and might be removed in future releases of `crawler4j`.